# getting error IndentationError: expected an indented block in python code

Tags: python

code is :

```
@property
    def get_cart_total(self):
    orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.get_total() for item in orderitem])
    return total

    @property
    def get_cart_item(self):
    orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for in orderitem])
    return total
```

someone please help on this

Comment: The lines underneath `def` should be indented, but they aren't.

Comment: Code needs to be indented after a `def my_function():` line. Also, decorators need to be aligned with the function they're decorating.

Answer (score 0):

Body of function should be indented:

```
@property
def get_cart_item(self):
    orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for in orderitem])
    return total

@property
def get_cart_item(self):
    orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for in orderitem])
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining a function, the code under `def()` needs to be indented.

```
@property
def get_cart_total(self):
    orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.get_total() for item in orderitem])
    return total

@property
def get_cart_item(self):
    orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for in orderitem])
    return total
```